# MongoDB schema with nested validation and strict mode

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have been able to have a correct schema validation with the following rules :

- Only the expected field should be saved (hence the strict mode)
- The `User.Account` should be nullable. If null, the required fields are not preventing the schema from being saved.
- If `User.Account` is not null, The validation rules to be respected (`.password` and `.email` required).
- I do NOT want to create an `AccountSchema` because it pollutes the `account` with an `_id`.

I have been able to do this with 2 schemas (`UserSchema` and `AccountSchema`). But as mentioned, the problem is that it creates a `_id` field in the `User.Account` field.

```
const AccountSchema: Mongoose.Schema = mongoose.Schema({
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true }
}, {
        strict: 'throw',
        useNestedStrict: true
    });

const UserSchema: Mongoose.Schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    account: AccountSchema
}, {
        strict: 'throw',
        useNestedStrict: true
    });
```

Here is a solution with only a `UserSchema` but the field strict mode and validation are not working as expected.

```
const UserSchema: Mongoose.Schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    account: {
        type: {
            password: { type: String, required: true },
            email: { type: String, required: true }
        },
        required: false
    }
}, {
        strict: 'throw',
        useNestedStrict: true
    });
```

Could anyone let me know what I am missing here?

By the way, I tried custom validation which does work, but it does not guarantee the object schema safety that `strict` mode should ensure.

Thanks